# what's the definition of "encoding-agnostic"?

Tags: encoding, lua

In lua 5.3 reference manual, we can see:

> Lua is also encoding-agnostic; it makes no assumptions about the contents of a string.

I can't understand what the sentence says.

Answer (score 5):

The same byte value in a string may represent different characters depending on the [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) used for that string. For example, the same value `\177` may represent `▒` in [Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) encoding or `±` in [Windows 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding.

Lua makes no assumption as to what the encoding of a given string is and the ambiguity needs to be resolved at the script level; in other words, your script needs to know whether to deal with the byte sequence as `Windows 1252`, `Code page 437`, `UTF-8`, or something else encoded string.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, a Lua string is a counted sequence of bytes. If you use a Lua string for binary data, the concept of character encodings is not relevant and does not interfere with the binary data. It that way, string is encoding-agnostic.

There are functions in the standard string library that treat string values as text—an uncounted, sequence of characters. There is no text but encoded text. An encoding maps a member of a character set to a sequence of bytes. A string would have the bytes for zero or more such encoded characters. To understand a string as text, you must know the character set and encoding. To use the string functions, the encoding should be compatible with `os.setlocale()`.